# Sorting nodes of dense XML files

Tags: xml, vb.net, sorting, xslt

I´m trying to sort some large XML files containing thousands of nodes, and as a common ground for all nodes I want to sort, there´s an attribute named "ID".

The element type preceding this attribute varies: It can have several names, such as **"Apt", "CenterDrill", "Reamer", "Cylinder", "Block", "Model", "Sweep", "Cone", "Probe"** and a few others. This is making it a mess for me to figure out an algorithm that could do the proper sorting regardless the name preceding the attribute.

I don´t want to mess with the order of the outter elements, that is, I want the elements **"Parametric Mills"**, **"Parametric Drills"**, **"Tool Holders"**, **"Probe Stylus"**, **"Polishers"** to remain in the same order. I want to sort the inner elements, as shown in the picture below.

[image: Original XML in the native application] [image: Sorted XML in the native application]

**Original XML content: Short Version (287 lines)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Tools>
    <Tool ID="Parametric Mills" Units="Millimeter" Stack="FALSE">
      <Force_data Input_lead="0" lead_dis="0.000000" helix_angle="0.000000" radial_rake="0.000000" rake_ball="0.000000" force_method="0" material="0" edge_type="0" 
     feed_limit="0.000000" chip_thickness="0.000000" force_limit="0.000000" power_limit="0.000000" plunge_feed="0" start_angle="0.000000" feed_drop="0.000000" cutoutput="0" force_resolution="0" force_resolution_distance="0.000000" 
            force_unit="1" force_cutchannel="0" force_ccstartangle="0.000000" force_ccfeedrop="0.000000" force_minfeedChange="0.000000" force_minfeedChange_def="1" force_mincutfeedrate="0.000000" 
             force_mincutfeedrate_def="1" force_aircutfeedrate="0.000000" force_aircutfeedrate_def="1" force_toolType="" force_edgeMaterial=""/>
      <Teeth>2</Teeth>
      <Type>Milling</Type>
      <Cutter>
        <Apt ID="10000" ParentID="" Type="FLAT END" >
          <D>12.7</D>
          <R>0</R>
          <E>0</E>
          <F>0</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>88.9</H>
          <StickoutLength>63.5</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>50.8</FluteLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
        <Apt ID="2" ParentID="" Type="BALL END" >
          <D>12.7</D>
          <R>6.35</R>
          <E>0</E>
          <F>6.35</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>88.9</H>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>50.8</FluteLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
        <Apt ID="33" ParentID="" Type="TAPERED BULL NOSE" >
          <D>12.7</D>
          <R>0</R>
          <E>0</E>
          <F>0</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>5</B>
          <H>88.9</H>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>50.8</FluteLength>
          <ShankDiameter>12.7</ShankDiameter>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
        <Apt ID="3000" ParentID="" Type="BULL NOSE" >
          <D>12.7</D>
          <R>2</R>
          <E>4.35</E>
          <F>2</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>88.9</H>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>50.8</FluteLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
      </Cutter>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-114.3</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
    </Tool>
    <Tool ID="Parametric Drills" Units="Millimeter" Stack="FALSE">
      <Force_data Input_lead="0" lead_dis="0.000000" helix_angle="0.000000" radial_rake="0.000000" rake_ball="0.000000" force_method="0" material="0" edge_type="0" 
     feed_limit="0.000000" chip_thickness="0.000000" force_limit="0.000000" power_limit="0.000000" plunge_feed="0" start_angle="0.000000" feed_drop="0.000000" cutoutput="0" force_resolution="0" force_resolution_distance="0.000000" 
            force_unit="1" force_cutchannel="0" force_ccstartangle="0.000000" force_ccfeedrop="0.000000" force_minfeedChange="0.000000" force_minfeedChange_def="1" force_mincutfeedrate="0.000000" 
             force_mincutfeedrate_def="1" force_aircutfeedrate="0.000000" force_aircutfeedrate_def="1" force_toolType="" force_edgeMaterial=""/>
      <Teeth>2</Teeth>
      <Type>HoleMaking</Type>
      <Cutter>
        <Apt ID="5000" ParentID="" Type="DRILL" >
          <D>9.525</D>
          <R>0</R>
          <E>0</E>
          <F>0</F>
          <A>31</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>101.6</H>
          <StickoutLength>76.2</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>63.5</FluteLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
        <Reamer ID="111" ParentID="" DRILLMILL="FALSE" Type="Reamer" >
          <ChamferLength>0.5</ChamferLength>
          <D>12</D>
          <H>100</H>
          <ShankDiameter>12</ShankDiameter>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <MAXIMUMMATERIALREMOVAL>0</MAXIMUMMATERIALREMOVAL>
          <FluteLength>63.5</FluteLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Reamer>
        <CenterDrill ID="3" ParentID="" DRILLMILL="FALSE" Type="CenterDrill" >
          <ChamferAngle>60</ChamferAngle>
          <H>50</H>
          <PilotAngle>31</PilotAngle>
          <D>3</D>
          <PilotLength>3</PilotLength>
          <ShankDiameter>12</ShankDiameter>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>11.69552</FluteLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </CenterDrill>
      </Cutter>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-127</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
    </Tool>
    <Tool ID="Tool Holders" Units="Millimeter" Stack="FALSE">
      <Force_data Input_lead="0" lead_dis="0.000000" helix_angle="0.000000" radial_rake="0.000000" rake_ball="0.000000" force_method="0" material="0" edge_type="0" 
     feed_limit="0.000000" chip_thickness="0.000000" force_limit="0.000000" power_limit="0.000000" plunge_feed="0" start_angle="0.000000" feed_drop="0.000000" cutoutput="0" force_resolution="0" force_resolution_distance="0.000000" 
            force_unit="1" force_cutchannel="0" force_ccstartangle="0.000000" force_ccfeedrop="0.000000" force_minfeedChange="0.000000" force_minfeedChange_def="1" force_mincutfeedrate="0.000000" 
             force_mincutfeedrate_def="1" force_aircutfeedrate="0.000000" force_aircutfeedrate_def="1" force_toolType="" force_edgeMaterial=""/>
      <Teeth>2</Teeth>
      <Type>Turning</Type>
      <Holder>
        <Block ID="455" ParentID="">
          <Width>25.4</Width>
          <Length>25.4</Length>
          <Height>101.6</Height>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Block>
        <Cylinder ID="1" ParentID="">
          <Radius>50</Radius>
          <Height>10</Height>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Cylinder>
        <Cone ID="50000" ParentID="">
          <ButtomRadius>30</ButtomRadius>
          <TopRadius>10</TopRadius>
          <Height>50</Height>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Cone>
      </Holder>
    </Tool>
    <Tool ID="Probe Stylus" Units="Millimeter" Stack="FALSE">
      <Force_data Input_lead="0" lead_dis="0.000000" helix_angle="0.000000" radial_rake="0.000000" rake_ball="0.000000" force_method="0" material="0" edge_type="0" 
     feed_limit="0.000000" chip_thickness="0.000000" force_limit="0.000000" power_limit="0.000000" plunge_feed="0" start_angle="0.000000" feed_drop="0.000000" cutoutput="0" force_resolution="0" force_resolution_distance="0.000000" 
            force_unit="1" force_cutchannel="0" force_ccstartangle="0.000000" force_ccfeedrop="0.000000" force_minfeedChange="0.000000" force_minfeedChange_def="1" force_mincutfeedrate="0.000000" 
             force_mincutfeedrate_def="1" force_aircutfeedrate="0.000000" force_aircutfeedrate_def="1" force_toolType="" force_edgeMaterial=""/>
      <Type>Probing</Type>
      <Cutter>
        <Probe ID="11500" ParentID="" Type="Standard">
          <SphereDiameter>5.00126</SphereDiameter>
          <Height>101.6</Height>
          <StemDiameter>2.99974</StemDiameter>
          <Length>101.6</Length>
          <MaxRPM>0</MaxRPM>
          <StemRGB>-4144960</StemRGB>
          <StickoutLength>76.2</StickoutLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Probe>
        <Probe ID="10455" ParentID="" Type="Cylinder">
          <SphereDiameter>10</SphereDiameter>
          <Height>10</Height>
          <StemDiameter>3</StemDiameter>
          <Length>50</Length>
          <MaxRPM>0</MaxRPM>
          <StemRGB>-4144960</StemRGB>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Probe>
        <Probe ID="11111" ParentID="" Type="Disk">
          <SphereDiameter>20</SphereDiameter>
          <Height>3</Height>
          <Height2>5</Height2>
          <Diameter2>3</Diameter2>
          <PinOffset>8</PinOffset>
          <StemDiameter>6</StemDiameter>
          <Length>50</Length>
          <MaxRPM>0</MaxRPM>
          <StemRGB>-4144960</StemRGB>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Probe>
      </Cutter>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-127</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
    </Tool>
    <Tool ID="Polishers" Units="Millimeter" Stack="FALSE">
      <Force_data Input_lead="0" lead_dis="0.000000" helix_angle="0.000000" radial_rake="0.000000" rake_ball="0.000000" force_method="0" material="0" edge_type="0" 
     feed_limit="0.000000" chip_thickness="0.000000" force_limit="0.000000" power_limit="0.000000" plunge_feed="0" start_angle="0.000000" feed_drop="0.000000" cutoutput="0" force_resolution="0" force_resolution_distance="0.000000" 
            force_unit="1" force_cutchannel="0" force_ccstartangle="0.000000" force_ccfeedrop="0.000000" force_minfeedChange="0.000000" force_minfeedChange_def="1" force_mincutfeedrate="0.000000" 
             force_mincutfeedrate_def="1" force_aircutfeedrate="0.000000" force_aircutfeedrate_def="1" force_toolType="" force_edgeMaterial=""/>
      <Type>Polisher</Type>
      <Cutter>
        <Apt ID="50" ParentID="" Type="FLAT END"  PolishType="Polisher">
          <D>38.1</D>
          <R>0</R>
          <E>0</E>
          <F>0</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>127</H>
          <StickoutLength>101.6</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>76.2</FluteLength>
          <ShankDiameter>19.05</ShankDiameter>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
        <Apt ID="65" ParentID="" Type="BALL END"  PolishType="Polisher">
          <D>20</D>
          <R>10</R>
          <E>0</E>
          <F>10</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>127</H>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>76.2</FluteLength>
          <ShankDiameter>19.05</ShankDiameter>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
        <Apt ID="42" ParentID="" Type="BULL NOSE"  PolishType="Polisher">
          <D>10</D>
          <R>2</R>
          <E>3</E>
          <F>2</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>127</H>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>76.2</FluteLength>
          <ShankDiameter>19.05</ShankDiameter>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
      </Cutter>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-114.3</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
    </Tool>
  </Tools>
```

**This is the expected XML content after sorting:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Tools>
    <Tool ID="Parametric Mills" Units="Millimeter" Stack="FALSE">
      <Force_data Input_lead="0" lead_dis="0.000000" helix_angle="0.000000" radial_rake="0.000000" rake_ball="0.000000" force_method="0" material="0" edge_type="0" 
     feed_limit="0.000000" chip_thickness="0.000000" force_limit="0.000000" power_limit="0.000000" plunge_feed="0" start_angle="0.000000" feed_drop="0.000000" cutoutput="0" force_resolution="0" force_resolution_distance="0.000000" 
            force_unit="1" force_cutchannel="0" force_ccstartangle="0.000000" force_ccfeedrop="0.000000" force_minfeedChange="0.000000" force_minfeedChange_def="1" force_mincutfeedrate="0.000000" 
             force_mincutfeedrate_def="1" force_aircutfeedrate="0.000000" force_aircutfeedrate_def="1" force_toolType="" force_edgeMaterial=""/>
      <Teeth>2</Teeth>
      <Type>Milling</Type>
      <Cutter>
      <Apt ID="2" ParentID="" Type="BALL END" >
          <D>12.7</D>
          <R>6.35</R>
          <E>0</E>
          <F>6.35</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>88.9</H>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>50.8</FluteLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
        <Apt ID="33" ParentID="" Type="TAPERED BULL NOSE" >
          <D>12.7</D>
          <R>0</R>
          <E>0</E>
          <F>0</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>5</B>
          <H>88.9</H>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>50.8</FluteLength>
          <ShankDiameter>12.7</ShankDiameter>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
        <Apt ID="3000" ParentID="" Type="BULL NOSE" >
          <D>12.7</D>
          <R>2</R>
          <E>4.35</E>
          <F>2</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>88.9</H>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>50.8</FluteLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
        <Apt ID="10000" ParentID="" Type="FLAT END" >
          <D>12.7</D>
          <R>0</R>
          <E>0</E>
          <F>0</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>88.9</H>
          <StickoutLength>63.5</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>50.8</FluteLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
      </Cutter>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-114.3</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
    </Tool>
    <Tool ID="Parametric Drills" Units="Millimeter" Stack="FALSE">
      <Force_data Input_lead="0" lead_dis="0.000000" helix_angle="0.000000" radial_rake="0.000000" rake_ball="0.000000" force_method="0" material="0" edge_type="0" 
     feed_limit="0.000000" chip_thickness="0.000000" force_limit="0.000000" power_limit="0.000000" plunge_feed="0" start_angle="0.000000" feed_drop="0.000000" cutoutput="0" force_resolution="0" force_resolution_distance="0.000000" 
            force_unit="1" force_cutchannel="0" force_ccstartangle="0.000000" force_ccfeedrop="0.000000" force_minfeedChange="0.000000" force_minfeedChange_def="1" force_mincutfeedrate="0.000000" 
             force_mincutfeedrate_def="1" force_aircutfeedrate="0.000000" force_aircutfeedrate_def="1" force_toolType="" force_edgeMaterial=""/>
      <Teeth>2</Teeth>
      <Type>HoleMaking</Type>
      <Cutter>
      <CenterDrill ID="3" ParentID="" DRILLMILL="FALSE" Type="CenterDrill" >
          <ChamferAngle>60</ChamferAngle>
          <H>50</H>
          <PilotAngle>31</PilotAngle>
          <D>3</D>
          <PilotLength>3</PilotLength>
          <ShankDiameter>12</ShankDiameter>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>11.69552</FluteLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </CenterDrill>
        <Reamer ID="111" ParentID="" DRILLMILL="FALSE" Type="Reamer" >
          <ChamferLength>0.5</ChamferLength>
          <D>12</D>
          <H>100</H>
          <ShankDiameter>12</ShankDiameter>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <MAXIMUMMATERIALREMOVAL>0</MAXIMUMMATERIALREMOVAL>
          <FluteLength>63.5</FluteLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Reamer>
        <Apt ID="5000" ParentID="" Type="DRILL" >
          <D>9.525</D>
          <R>0</R>
          <E>0</E>
          <F>0</F>
          <A>31</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>101.6</H>
          <StickoutLength>76.2</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>63.5</FluteLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
      </Cutter>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-127</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
    </Tool>
    <Tool ID="Tool Holders" Units="Millimeter" Stack="FALSE">
      <Force_data Input_lead="0" lead_dis="0.000000" helix_angle="0.000000" radial_rake="0.000000" rake_ball="0.000000" force_method="0" material="0" edge_type="0" 
     feed_limit="0.000000" chip_thickness="0.000000" force_limit="0.000000" power_limit="0.000000" plunge_feed="0" start_angle="0.000000" feed_drop="0.000000" cutoutput="0" force_resolution="0" force_resolution_distance="0.000000" 
            force_unit="1" force_cutchannel="0" force_ccstartangle="0.000000" force_ccfeedrop="0.000000" force_minfeedChange="0.000000" force_minfeedChange_def="1" force_mincutfeedrate="0.000000" 
             force_mincutfeedrate_def="1" force_aircutfeedrate="0.000000" force_aircutfeedrate_def="1" force_toolType="" force_edgeMaterial=""/>
      <Teeth>2</Teeth>
      <Type>Turning</Type>
      <Holder>
        <Cylinder ID="1" ParentID="">
          <Radius>50</Radius>
          <Height>10</Height>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Cylinder>
        <Block ID="455" ParentID="">
          <Width>25.4</Width>
          <Length>25.4</Length>
          <Height>101.6</Height>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Block>
        <Cone ID="50000" ParentID="">
          <ButtomRadius>30</ButtomRadius>
          <TopRadius>10</TopRadius>
          <Height>50</Height>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Cone>
      </Holder>
    </Tool>
    <Tool ID="Probe Stylus" Units="Millimeter" Stack="FALSE">
      <Force_data Input_lead="0" lead_dis="0.000000" helix_angle="0.000000" radial_rake="0.000000" rake_ball="0.000000" force_method="0" material="0" edge_type="0" 
     feed_limit="0.000000" chip_thickness="0.000000" force_limit="0.000000" power_limit="0.000000" plunge_feed="0" start_angle="0.000000" feed_drop="0.000000" cutoutput="0" force_resolution="0" force_resolution_distance="0.000000" 
            force_unit="1" force_cutchannel="0" force_ccstartangle="0.000000" force_ccfeedrop="0.000000" force_minfeedChange="0.000000" force_minfeedChange_def="1" force_mincutfeedrate="0.000000" 
             force_mincutfeedrate_def="1" force_aircutfeedrate="0.000000" force_aircutfeedrate_def="1" force_toolType="" force_edgeMaterial=""/>
      <Type>Probing</Type>
      <Cutter>
         <Probe ID="10455" ParentID="" Type="Cylinder">
          <SphereDiameter>10</SphereDiameter>
          <Height>10</Height>
          <StemDiameter>3</StemDiameter>
          <Length>50</Length>
          <MaxRPM>0</MaxRPM>
          <StemRGB>-4144960</StemRGB>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Probe>
        <Probe ID="11111" ParentID="" Type="Disk">
          <SphereDiameter>20</SphereDiameter>
          <Height>3</Height>
          <Height2>5</Height2>
          <Diameter2>3</Diameter2>
          <PinOffset>8</PinOffset>
          <StemDiameter>6</StemDiameter>
          <Length>50</Length>
          <MaxRPM>0</MaxRPM>
          <StemRGB>-4144960</StemRGB>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Probe>
        <Probe ID="11500" ParentID="" Type="Standard">
          <SphereDiameter>5.00126</SphereDiameter>
          <Height>101.6</Height>
          <StemDiameter>2.99974</StemDiameter>
          <Length>101.6</Length>
          <MaxRPM>0</MaxRPM>
          <StemRGB>-4144960</StemRGB>
          <StickoutLength>76.2</StickoutLength>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Probe>
      </Cutter>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-127</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
    </Tool>
    <Tool ID="Polishers" Units="Millimeter" Stack="FALSE">
      <Force_data Input_lead="0" lead_dis="0.000000" helix_angle="0.000000" radial_rake="0.000000" rake_ball="0.000000" force_method="0" material="0" edge_type="0" 
     feed_limit="0.000000" chip_thickness="0.000000" force_limit="0.000000" power_limit="0.000000" plunge_feed="0" start_angle="0.000000" feed_drop="0.000000" cutoutput="0" force_resolution="0" force_resolution_distance="0.000000" 
            force_unit="1" force_cutchannel="0" force_ccstartangle="0.000000" force_ccfeedrop="0.000000" force_minfeedChange="0.000000" force_minfeedChange_def="1" force_mincutfeedrate="0.000000" 
             force_mincutfeedrate_def="1" force_aircutfeedrate="0.000000" force_aircutfeedrate_def="1" force_toolType="" force_edgeMaterial=""/>
      <Type>Polisher</Type>
      <Cutter>
      <Apt ID="42" ParentID="" Type="BULL NOSE"  PolishType="Polisher">
          <D>10</D>
          <R>2</R>
          <E>3</E>
          <F>2</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>127</H>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>76.2</FluteLength>
          <ShankDiameter>19.05</ShankDiameter>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
        <Apt ID="50" ParentID="" Type="FLAT END"  PolishType="Polisher">
          <D>38.1</D>
          <R>0</R>
          <E>0</E>
          <F>0</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>127</H>
          <StickoutLength>101.6</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>76.2</FluteLength>
          <ShankDiameter>19.05</ShankDiameter>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>
        <Apt ID="65" ParentID="" Type="BALL END"  PolishType="Polisher">
          <D>20</D>
          <R>10</R>
          <E>0</E>
          <F>10</F>
          <A>0</A>
          <B>0</B>
          <H>127</H>
          <StickoutLength>0</StickoutLength>
          <R2>0</R2>
          <E2>0</E2>
          <F2>0</F2>
          <SpindleDirection>CW</SpindleDirection>
          <FluteLength>76.2</FluteLength>
          <ShankDiameter>19.05</ShankDiameter>
          <Alternate>off</Alternate>
        </Apt>        
      </Cutter>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-114.3</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
    </Tool>
  </Tools>
```

This is the code I´m using, but the output file is being returned as a **single line** XML file... I´m kind of lost about how I could sort the nodes containing the ID attribute after the tags **"Apt", "CenterDrill", "Reamer", "Cylinder", "Block", "Model", "Sweep", "Cone", "Probe"** and a few others **without messing with** nodes that contain the ID attribute preceded by the **"Tool"** or **"DrivenPoint"** tags/nodes.

I´ve researched and googled a lot for a solution, but they all seems to be based in much simpler XML structures... I don´t mind to write code for each node type, below in my code I try to do something with the "Probe" node, but it´s not working either... I get a 1kb output file with a single line within it...

Any suggestions?

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Public Class Form1

    Private Function ReorderByMaterialThickness(ByRef inFile As String, ByRef outFile As String)

        Try
            Dim document As XElement = XElement.Load(inFile)

            Dim sortedTables As XElement() = document.Elements("Probe").OrderBy(Function(t) CInt(t.Element("ID"))).ToArray()
            document.ReplaceAll(sortedTables)
            document.Save(outFile)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Something went wrong!")
        End Try

        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ReorderByMaterialThickness("C:\Testes\Original.xml", "C:\Testes\Sorted.xml")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How about using a technology that is dedicated to XML? Ideally, XSLT.

Comment: If one could point me in the right direction I´d love to learn it. Currently I´m clueless about how to use it...

Comment: You can try to turn this question into an XSLT question, among other things by tagging it with `xslt` instead. But before: make sure you include a minimal, complete sample of both your input and output documents here, not as a link and that many lines of code. Help on this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Keep in mind: I do not know if there is a simple solution in vb.net, too - there might be one.

Comment: Shouldn't the sorting be controlled by the UI layout instead of inside the file? Your program shouldn't care how the data is sorted, it should include the correct sorting to show it in the UI (preferably, something the user can adjust)

Comment: Actually the UI you see is from the application that reads this XML... It´s not something I coded... What I need is a function that can read and sort this XML because the app that reads it is unable to do it...

Comment: Hi Mathias, the xml files I added as hyperlinks contains the minimal set of variances that needs to be covered, in 287 lines... The real xml files contains 45K lines... The ones I linked are in Google Drive, which allows them to be previewed so all one has to do is do copy and paste... I thinks this makes the post cleaner...

Comment: No, this makes the post worth closing and deleting. Links can become dead in the future, and then the question will be incomplete. Please include the minimal XML samples here. (Please prefix names with `@`, otherwise they will not be notified.)

Comment: Ok. What do you mean with prefixing names? Last but not least, where can I find all this guidelines about prefixing and best practices so I don´t make the same mistakes in the future?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-zWGlBf98V0aDM4UjJpZjBxaVU can not be viewed, I am told to ask the owner for permission. So consider to include the necessary snippets inline, I don't think the graphics demonstrate what you want to sort.

Comment: Martin, I added the snippets as suggested by Mathias. It looks better now. About the pictures, look at the child elements at left and right, they are in a different order... The parents remains in the same order...

Comment: (Sorry for cluttering the comments section, but here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's a lot going on in the comments, but I didn't notice until I got back, however I believe this does what you're wanting. It only sorts elements with 2 or more ancestors, so I believe it only targets the "inner" elements with ID's and sorts them. When I tried it with your original XML, I got the output you said you wanted.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Original.xml");
    foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Elements().Any(y => y.Attribute("ID") != null) && x.Ancestors().Count() >= 2))
    {
        el.ReplaceNodes(el.Elements().OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Attribute("ID").Value)));
    }
    doc.Save("newFile.xml");
```

I was a bit confused by your post, but I thought this is what you were asking for.

And if you don't want to use XDocument:

```
    XElement doc = XElement.Load("Original.xml");
    foreach (XElement el in doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Elements().Any(y => y.Attribute("ID") != null) && x.Ancestors().Count() >= 2))
    {
        el.ReplaceNodes(el.Elements().OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Attribute("ID").Value)));
    }
    doc.Save("newFile.xml");
```

Comment: It almost worked! However, your code is messing up with the node <Force_data>

Comment: I´m sorry, I think the original xml break the <Force_data> node in multiple lines because it is very long, and when we output it with your code, it is written in a single line. I made a mistake, it´s not that your code is messing up with the source, it is just writing it in a single line. My bad.

Comment: Oh, no problem at all! I was just curious so I could fix it. Cool.

Comment: Golgothan3, there´s a small header and footer in the original xml code I omitted, however when I try to use your algorithm with it, I get an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." - I don´t get why this small header is causing this since it´s just an informative node... I´ll update the original xml sample... could you please figure out what´s throwing this exception? When I debug it I can´t see exactly what line is causing the exception because the same line is parsed properly without the header...

Comment: Yeah, I can check it out.

Comment: Golgothan3, I don´t know how to add code in a comment, so here´s the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-zWGlBf98V0WVNNY1N4VHJiRm8/view?usp=sharing  - Notice ID is not an integer, is alpha numeric in this sample, but this has nothing to do with the issue I mentioned above. (Header / footer) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102637/discussion-between-golgothan3-and-daniel-santos).

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT, applying the following XSL transformation to your XML file will produce the required result:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Cutter | Holder">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="@ID" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mT

Comment: Oh this post is a so rich! I´ll give it a try in xslt as well... I thin it´s important for me to learn it!

Comment: Michael, I tried that in the emulator you shared... it looks perfect! I have to learn xls!